# how to query table data with count and condition

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I am new and I need given output from the following scenario.
Required following output

### |Code| Unit Name| Type| Count|

| U-1| Unit 1 name | MCQ | 25

| U-1| Unit 1 name | SEQ| 20

| U-1| Unit 1 name | Long| 50|

| U-2| Unit 2 name | MCQ | 25|

I have the Subject Dropdown when I select the Subjectname from the dropdown I want to populate the Units table with unit code, unit name and the number of questions along with their type. ( MCQ, SEQ, etc)

the classes are Subjects, Topics, and Questions.

```
 public class Subject
    {
        public int Id  { get; set; }
        public string? SubjectText { get; set; }

        //relationship to topics (one to many)
        public List<Topic>? Topic { get; set; }
    }

public class Topic
    {
        public int Id  { get; set; }
        public string? TopicText { get; set; }

       //relationship ( one to many)
        public List<Question> Question { get; set; }

        //navigation back to  subjects
        public int SubjectId { get; set; }
        public Subject Subject { get; set; }
  }

public class Question
    {
        public int Id  { get; set; }
        public string? QuestionText { get; set; }
        public QuestionTypes QuestionType { get; set; }
        public DifficultyLevel DifficultyLevel { get; set; }

        //navigation back to Topics
        public int TopicId { get; set; }
        public Topic? Topic { get; set; }
    }
 // question types and difficulty level are enums
public enum QuestionTypes
    {
        
        MCQ =1,
        SEQ,
        Long_Question,
        Fill_In_The_Blanks
    }
public enum DifficultyLevel
    {
        Very_Easy = 1,
        Easy,
        Moderate,
        Hard,
        Very_Hard,  
    }
```

my VM for the  table is

```
public class TopicsWithQCountsVM
    {
        public int Code { get; set; }
        public string? TopicText { get; set; }
        public QuestionTypes QType { get; set; }
        public List<int>? mcqCount { get; set; }    // Multiple Choices Questions
        public List<int>? seqCount { get; set; }    // Short Exam Questions
        public List<int>? longQCount { get; set; }    // long Questions
        public List<int>? FillinBlankCount { get; set; }   // fill in the blanks
    }
```

I want to display all the units along with their QuestionsTypes(MCQ,SEQ,Long) and total Count  when a user select the subject from dropdownlist. The dropdown list is dynamically populated from database table called Subjects. I have a javascript function that is loading the two units from the controller and posting them back to view

controller code

```
public JsonResult Subject(int id)
        {
            var sl = _context.Subjects.Where(s => s.GradeId == id).ToList();
            return new JsonResult(sl);
        }
        public JsonResult GetTableData(int id)
        {

            var query = _context.Topics
            .Join(_context.Questions, Topic => Topic.Id, Question => Question.Id, (Topic, Question) => new { Topic, Question })
            .Where(u => u.Topic.SubjectId == id)
            .ToListAsync();

            var query = _context.Topics.Where(s => s.SubjectId == id).Include(t => t.Question.Count).GroupBy(q => q.TopicText).FirstOrDefault();
            var objtopiclist = new TopicsWithQCountsVM();
            
            var query = _context.Topics.Where(s => s.SubjectId == id).ToList();
            for each (var item in query)
            {
              
                var seqcount = _context.Questions.Where(q => q.TopicId == item.Id && q.QuestionType == QuestionTypes.SEQ).Count();
                
            }
            return new JsonResult(query);
        }
```

my View is

```
    


// on change of SubjectDDL                      
            $('#SubjectDDL').change(function() {
                var id = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/Dashboard/GetTableData?id=' + id,
                    data: '{}',
                    
                    success: function(response) {
                        var trHTML = '';
                        $.each(response, function(i, item) {
                            trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.code + '</td><td>' + item.topicText + '</td></tr>';
                            //trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.rank + '</td><td>' + item.content + '</td><td>' + item.UID + '</td></tr>';
                        });
                        $('#tableUnits').append(trHTML);
                    }
                });
            });
 <!-- DropDown section-->
                    <div class="table  table-hover">
                        <div class="row"> <h5>Please select the appropriate category</h5></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-12">
                                <label asp-for="GradeName" class="control-label"></label>
                                <select id="GradeDDL" asp-for="GradeId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Grades"> <option selected disabled>---Select Grade---</option>  </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-12">
                                <label asp-for="SubjectName" class="control-label"></label>
                                <select id="SubjectDDL" asp-for="SubjectId" onconchange="selectedText" class="form-control"> <option selected disabled>---Select Subject---</option> </select>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-12">
                                <label></label>
                                @*<button asp-controller="dashboard" asp-action="LoadUnitsAndQuestionCount" asp-route-id="@Model.SubjectId" type="button" > Load Units </button>*@
                                @*<button  type="submit", class="form-control btn btn-secondary"> Load Units</button>*@
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
                            <table id="tableUnits" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                                <thead> <h4>Units </h4></thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Unit Code</th>
                                    <th>Unit Name</th>
                                    <th>Type</th>
                                    <th>Count</th>
                                    <th>Given Question</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> unit1 </td>
                                    <td> Unit Title </td>
                                    <td> mcq </td>
                                    <td> 25 </td>
                                    <td> <input type="number" /> </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I tried my best to do but I don't know how to write the LINQ query that meets my needs (I know my method code is full of bugs )
I want to use the VM model please help me with this problem.
thanks

Comment: It's not very clear what exactly you would like to do, What I get from your explanation is something like, first there is `subject dropdown`, then based on that you would like to load `unit` where is the unit class or what it contains? `Subject` should have a relation with `unit` based on your explanation. So please clarify this first. I think you are trying to load cascading dropdown and finally want to load something based on the dropdown selected. Please share your details what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: In addition, please share your database schema structure if possible or sample of your existing data.